# A seven letter word - the meaning doesn't change if you remove letters

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, language

I am a seven letter word. If you remove one letter from me my meaning does not change. If you remove two letters from me my meaning still does not change, and if you remove three letters from me, my meaning still does not change.

Even if you remove all letters my meaning won't change. What word is this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The answer is a postbox/mailbox because if you remove a physical letter from it, it remains a mailbox; its meaning is still to hold letters. You can remove all the letters, but it will still be a mailbox.

Comment: Shame for the difference in languages, in dutch 'envelop' is 7 letters, but the english 'envelope' doesn't fit.

Comment: Does a mailbox have a meaning, though?

Comment: @Jasper The word itself does

Comment: @warspyking Though that was apparently what was intended, I still think that makes no sense. You remove the letters from the *object* and then the meaning of the *word* doesn't change. This interpretation requires "me" to refer to both things interchangeably, while they are definitely separate concepts. It would be like saying "if you cut me in half, my shape doesn't change" for a rope (after all, it's still a rope and the shape of the word definitely hasn't changed).

Comment: @Jasper please see the tag lateral-thinking :)

Comment: Lateral thinking is not an excuse for incorrect grammar...

Comment: @Jasper Well than downvote the question for it being a poorly written question, not the answer :)

Comment: Of course I wouldn't downvote the answer over something like this (and I never did), I just raised an issue that only arises within the context of the answer (even if it was the intended answer).

Comment: @Jasper Just making sure. Wasn't accusing you of anything?

Comment: This is my single best achievement and the votes go up every now and then (more and more)

Comment: Reverting edit: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/83

Comment: @ffao Part of me wants to explain how I'm not allowed to spoiler it, another part of me decides not to complain because it's already upvoted a ton xD Why were you looking at the answers before solving it in the first place? It's clearly accepted.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: (For the avoidance of doubt, that's a comment on the question and its intended answer, rather than on warspyking's correct identification of that answer.)

Comment: @Gareth I laughed so hard.

Comment: @warspyking What does [movies.se]'s spoiler policy have to do with anything though?

Comment: @rand al'thor A notification from a dead post by a guy who disappeared for a year. A rare occasion I'll never see again :O

Comment: This answer is never going to die, I'm STILL getting upvotes for it lol

Answer (score 97):

NOTHING. The pronunciation of this in various accents could be rendered as NOTHIN' (one letter removed), NOT'IN' (two letters removed), or NOT'N' (three letters removed). And of course if you remove all the letters you're left with *nothing*!

Comment: Very creative indeed

Comment: @skv - Are you being sarcastic? This just sprang to mind as soon as I saw "if you remove all letters my meaning won't change".

Comment: I think he was not being sarcastic, and I agree. Now am _I_ being sarcastic? <grin>

Comment: @Lohoris Judging from your upvote, no, you're not being sarcastic ;-)

Comment: Is this the era before spoiler tags was a thing? (That is, except for the answer below this one)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac No, but this is the question chosen to [appear in the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), and posts with any kind of formatting, such as spoilertagging, are ineligible to appear there. See the [revision history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/2823/revisions) and [hidden comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/2823/edit) on the top answer.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> **NOTHING**

Because:

> if you remove "G", it becomes "NOTHIN" which has the same meaning, nothing. Remove N, it becomes "NOTHI" which means nothing. "I", "NOTH", which means nothing. "H", "NOT", which arguably does not make sense in this context. "T", "NO", somewhat similar. "N", nothing big.

Comment: this answer has already been submitted. If you can think of a unique answer please submit it but don't copy answers please.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No, his answer is different. At first glance, it might seem to be a duplicate of Rand al'Thor's answer, but it isn't. He means that nonsensical fragments of a meaningful word mean nothing. See, `"NOT", which arguably does not make sense in this context.` because it has a meaning. I thought the answer was very creative and original; I dont think this deserved that downvote (presumably by you).

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine it still submits the same answer. His explanation is it will always mean nothing and Rand says 'And of course if you remove all the letters you're left with nothing!' - same explanation - rand just adds some other stuff. (PS I haven't downvoted - the answer is currently at +2 -2)

Answer (score 2):

If we consider any random combination of 7 letters or characters of all existing writing systems, we will get not only all possible words with seven letters, but also get the words without meaning in any language (depends on the concept of word). So, any of the words resulting from the last group is a correct answer: Regardless of the letters that are removed from this word the meaning would not change, this meaning is, of course: NONE.

This leave us with: letters!/7!(letters-7)! - known_words, correct answers for this puzzle.

Comment: Unfortunately the puzzle begins "I am a seven-letter *word*" and what you are describing is 7-letter sequences that are *not* words. Neat idea, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan What is a word?

Comment: @enzo I assume you ask that question to make a point. Unfortunately I can think of at least two quite different points you might be making with it, to which I would give quite different answers. Would you like to be more explicit?