# Removing my characters does not change my meaning

Tags: word, wordplay

I start with nothing. If you remove 1, 2 or 3 of my characters then my meaning does not change. What 5-letter word am I?

Comment: Closely related: [A seven letter word - the meaning doesn't change if you remove letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4814/5373) (particularly my answer there)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question under our "not fully defined" reason. There have been quite a number of answers which seem to fit the text of the question well, and none of them are the intended one. Therefore the puzzle is not well-defined enough to have a single, unarguable answer.

Comment: I have updated the question and vote to reopen it. Once you see the answer you will be convinced that it is quite unambiguous and unarguable.

Comment: I am also satisfied with the update, as it now seems to be much less ambiguous. At the very least all the existing answers are now invalidated. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Please [do not make edits that invalidates answers](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6986/70545).

Comment: Sorry for invalidating previous answers. But this was the only way I could keep the question open.

Comment: I have edited some of the answers to explain that they were written before the question was edited.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky That's fair :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose:

> EMPTY - it is nothing

> Removing Y, it gives EMPT that sounds like EMPTY

> Removing P, it gives EMT that sounds like EMPTY

> Removing E, it gives MT that sounds like EMPTY

> I guess if you removed all the characters, it'd also be EMPTY

Comment: That's it you got it! Very well done! I got the idea from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=th4mkp6m4Ls

Answer (score 10):

**Note:** This answer was submitted prior to it being specified as a five-letter word.

I think the answer might simply be

> NONE

Reasoning

> NONE
>  NON, as a prefix, meaning "the absence of".
>  NO
>  [O](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/o) (definition 4)

Comment: I was about to post rot13(abjg, abg, ab, b), which is somewhat similar, but yours is a bit better.

Comment: Great answer! It is not my intended answer, but it works well.

Comment: Note the recent [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/106581/2) made on the puzzle. You may want to give a disclaimer in your answer to avoid the risk of downvotes :)

Comment: @riskymysteries Thanks, have edited.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** This answer was submitted prior to it being specified as a five-letter word.

As an extra answer:

> NOT ONE -> NO ONE -> NONE -> NON
>  All potential meanings of nothing.

Comment: Nice answer, but not what I was looking for. Note you have two words here.

Comment: agreed - I just thought it was too coincidental not to post :)

Comment: Note the recent [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/106581/2) made on the puzzle. You may want to give a disclaimer in your answer to avoid the risk of downvotes :)

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** This answer was submitted prior to it being specified as a five-letter word.

> 0000

If you remove any number of characters it has the same meaning

Comment: Ooh, this is a neat nugget!

Comment: But the question is tagged wordplay, not digit-play.

Comment: Note the recent [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/106581/2) made on the puzzle. You may want to give a disclaimer in your answer to avoid the risk of downvotes :)

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This answer was submitted prior to it being specified as a five-letter word.

Could it be

> Nothing?

Because

> I start with nothing.

> 'Nothing' starts with nothing (as in prefix nothing)

> If you remove 1, 2 or 3 of my characters then my meaning does not change.

> I think it works in two ways. One could be actual characters (people). You are removing people from nothing, so it still is nothing.

> But, on the other side of the coin, characters could mean letters of the word, so NOTHING with one letter taken away is NOTHIN', which sounds the same and really is the same word, 2 letters could be NOT'IN', and 3 letters could be NOT''N' (Thank you to [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/a-seven-letter-word-the-meaning-doesnt-change-if-you-remove-letters?rq=1)).

Am I correct?

Comment: Nice answer.  Perhaps also rot13(Erzbir 3 pbhyq yrnir ABG V nf va "abg 1"?) :)

Comment: Remoe3 could leave not I as in "not 1"? meaning      (sorry don't know)

Comment: There is not even one..? As in nothing?  I was just adding another reason for your answer.

Comment: Good answer, but not quite what I was looking for

Comment: Note the recent [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/106581/2) made on the puzzle. You may want to give a disclaimer in your answer to avoid the risk of downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

> No - No yes
>
> Neo - Means new, get rid of old
>
> Gone - It's gone, nothing left
>
> Goner - Something gone, nothing
>
> It almost fits all the requirements, I stretched a bit with neo, though.

Another one is

> No - Nothing
>
> Non - Nonfiction means no fiction, it is the nothing prefix
>
> None - Nothing left
>
> Noone - No people